# NLP based Data Preprocessing Method to Improve Disease Name Prediction Using CRF and Word Embedding

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, lstm, word-embeddings

I built a model( using CRF along bi lstm) to Predict New Disease Name/Entities from medical text data but the problem is Disease name appears only 5,6 times in 1 text file  but on average text file consists of 500-1000 words and this increase False negative (FN).  when i test model on newly/real time Data set its only Predict 60% disease Names (On new dataset).

In total i have 16000 words having  (O-tags which represent Irrelevant words) and only 220 words having B-Disease tags. 
My model precision is 73 % and recall 61% f1 score is 66 %. Parameter on which i trained model

```
params = {
    'dim': 300,
    'dim_chars': 100,
    'dropout': 0.5,
    'num_oov_buckets': 1,
    'epochs': 75,
    'batch_size': 7,
    'buffer': 15000,
    'char_lstm_size': 25,
    'lstm_size': 100,
    'words': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.words.txt')),
    'chars': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.chars.txt')),
    'tags': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.tags.txt')),
    'glove': str(Path(DATADIR, 'glove.npz'))
}
[file having complete code][1]
```

Case #2 : When i trained model only on those lines which include disease Names this cause High False Positive  .

Q1 .Should i remove half lines from every text file so irrevlant dataset decrease.

Q2. Or increase data set without removing half lines from a text file (increase train data set size rather using 80 files  train data on 200 files) As i am using Neural Architectures for Named Entity Recognition and Neural Architectures Want more training data Set

I am using following [Code / Library , tf_ner](https://github.com/guillaumegenthial/tf_ner)

i am using 2nd model mention in the library  "chars_lstm_lstm_crf"

This model include :

```
 GloVe 840B vectors

 Chars embeddings

 Chars bi-LSTM

 Bi-LSTM

 CRF
```

Related Research Paper 
Neural Architectures for Named Entity Recognition by Lample et al.
==>>>

[Research Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01360.pdf)